# Devolver valor de una función normal que a su vez le devuelve una promesa una función asíncrona

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo este código en el cual llamo a una función **f()** normal a una función asíncrona **wait()**.

```js
async function wait() {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

  return 10;
}

function f() {
  // muestra 10 después de 1 segundo
  wait().then(result => alert(result));
}

f();
```

Pero me gustaría que la función **f()** a su vez devolviese un return con el resultado del **result** devuelto en el .then : seía lago así como esto:

```js
function f() {
  // muestra 10 después de 1 segundo
  wait().then(result => //aquí quiero hacer algo como un return de la función principal f(), pero n osé cómo hacerlo);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Algunas aclaraciones importantes:**

1 - Si quieres "mostrar" el 10 (como dice el comentario de la función `F()`) solo haz un `console.log()` y retorna la promesa.

2 - Las funciones solo pueden retornar **1 valor**.

Teniendo en cuenta la primera aclaración, no puedes mostrar directamente el *10* si no llamaste a la función que lo contenga.

Asumiendo que necesites retornar tanto la promesa como el numero 10 para luego usarlo dentro de la función `f()`, y teniendo en cuenta mi segunda aclaración (*Las funciones solo pueden retornar **1 valor***), agregues ambos valores dentro de un objeto o un array y luego lo retornes. Por ejemplo:

```js
function wait() {
    const myPromise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve("Resolve de la promesa"), 1000));
    const data = 10;
    return { data, myPromise }; // retornamos ambas variables
}

function f() {
    const { data, myPromise } = wait();
    // muestra 10 después de 1 segundo
    console.log(data);
    // muestra la respuesta de la promesa
    myPromise.then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
    })
}

f();
```

***nota**: ten en cuenta que eliminé el async y el await*

Comment: Me ha ayudado tu respuesta. Mi caso sería el segundo, lo que pasa es que quiero mantener el async en la función **wait()** porque dentro de ella es posible que me interese tener varias promesas que se ejecuten en serie y en orden todas (cada una con su correspondiente **Await**) y al final de todas devolver el **return { data, myPromise }**